# Mysql automated installation stuck

Tags: mysql, bash, automation, installation, apt-get

I have written a script to install some set of packages to a list of servers. When i execute the script mysql installation got stuck at "enter the root password" section. Is there anything i need to modify in my script ? Advice me.

Is there any way to pass the mysql root password through the script itself ?

Below is the code which i used

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read -p "Enter server name : " servername
echo "Installing package on $servername"
ssh "${servername}" sudo apt-get -y install apache2 mysql-server
```

[Installation got stuck here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X52h.png)

Even if I enter the password, it wouldn't proceed to the next step. I am very beginner for scripting. Let me know where to modify the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read -p "Enter server name : " servername
echo "Installing package on $servername"
ssh "${Host}" "echo 'mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server/root_password password your_password' | debconf-set-selections && \
echo 'mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server/root_password_again password your_password' | debconf-set-selections && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install apache2 apache2-doc apache2-utils mysql-server"
```

**The above code does the trick**

**Note** : *Backslash (\) are used for readability. They allow to continue the command on a next line.*

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get` is a front-end to `dpkg` and `debconf` and is running in interactive mode by default, even `-y` won't change that.

`mysql-server` installation requires the root password to be interactively entered during installation.

To fully automatically install MySQL server on a Debian based Linux distro, you can enter non-interactive mode and preset the MySQL root password as follows.

In the shell where you want to run the process, execute:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"
```

Then

```
apt-get install -y debconf-utils
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password yournewpassword"
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again yournewpassword"
apt-get install -y mysql-server-5.6
```